# How can I fix this issue writing column headers in a pre-existing Excel sheet containing a data table?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl, xlsx

I'm new to using pandas and writing in Excel files using code so please forgive me if there's an obvious answer to this. I have a single Excel sheet with a few columns of data, with empty cells where the column headers should be. I want to use this program to write in the headers, but I'm having an issue with saving and closing it. Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
headers = []

# code not shown, but just prompts user for column headers and saves in list 'headers'

#open .xlsx file
book = load_workbook(r'path.xlsx')
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'path.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') 

#write column headers from list into empty cells
writer.columns = headers[:]


#save and close
writer.save('path.xlsx')
writer.close()
book.close()
```

Here is the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-84b69076ad08> in <module>
     30    # workbook.write(cell, h)
     31 
---> 32 writer.save('path.xlsx')
     33 writer.close()
     34 book.close()

TypeError: save() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Based on what I've read, it seems like this is actually a pretty generic error that doesn't indicate what the actual problem is. I tried a few variations of save(), including using the whole raw path as an argument and not including any arguments. Moreover, when I temporarily get rid of the save line just to see if the close lines work, they don't. So perhaps there is something more fundamentally wrong with my code than just these few lines?

Comment: From the documentation I found online, you should write `writer.save()` without a path. It saves to the path you opened it with. If you want to save to a new name, it's not through `save()` you do it. Ref: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html

Comment: Subtlety in case you're new to Python: when calling a class method, `self` is always added first, so when the message says `save() takes 1 positional arg`, that arg is `self`, so that means 0 args to `writer.save()`.

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure what I changed in between the last time I tried that and now, but it works now! However, I now have a much bigger issue which is that it wiped the Excel sheet blank and there's no headers anyway. Should I create a separate thread for this, or does anyone see a reason for this?

Comment: I think it would be best to ask a separate question for that, it would confuse the issue to try to combine it here. The SO site is best suited to questions that ask one clear and specific question per post.